# Apple App Privacy Data Collection: If we require the user's email to create an account in an app, does that count as "collecting" the email address?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, privacy, data-collection

I'm filling out the App Privacy Data Collection disclosure in the App Store and I am wondering if I need to disclosure we "collect" email addresses of the users.

We collect the email in order to create an account in the app but we don't share it with third-party services and we don't use it for tracking. Do I need to disclosure it as Data Collection in the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation: `The purpose of the label is to help your customers understand what data is collected from your app and how it is used.`

You collect email addresses therefore you need to disclose it.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/